# how to Set value in multidimensional array php

Tags: php

I am working in formbuilder api, i am struck in following function,following array

```
Array
(
    [label] => Course
    [field_type] => checkboxes
    [required] => 1
    [field_options] => stdClass Object
        (
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [label] => BE
                            [checked] => 
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [label] => MBA
                            [checked] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [cid] => c11
)
```

Value : BE

How to set checked = 1  at label = BE in options array... Please help me to do this

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Yes..but i dint get checked  = 1

Comment: @HalfCrazed 'checked' is an element of an Object.. so something like `$var['field_options']->options[0]->checked = 1;`

Comment: how to set based on label BE

Comment: `$var['field_options']->options[0]->checked =  $var['field_options']->options[0]->label;`

Comment: Thank u  Half crazed and chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array is in a variable called `$fb`.

The simple and probably useless answer is :-

```
$fb['field_options']->options[0]->checked = 1;
```

But if all you know is that you want to set `checked = 1` where `label = 'BE'` then you will have to go looking for the right occurance to change.

```
foreach ( $fb['field_options']->options as $option ) {
    if ( $option->label == 'BE' ) {
        $option->checked = 1;
    }
}
```